# Encountered an import error while working with React Redux, specifically related to the mutation function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I hope you're all doing well. I'm currently working on a React project using Redux Toolkit, and I've run into an issue that I'm having trouble resolving. I'd appreciate any help or insights you can provide.

The problem is occurring within a component named "Project." Below is the code snippet for my Redux store:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import userReducer from './features/userSlice';

import { authApi } from './api/authApi';
import { userApi } from './api/userApi';
import { projectsApi } from './api/projectApi'
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        auth: userReducer,
        [authApi.reducerPath]: authApi.reducer,
        [userApi.reducerPath]: userApi.reducer,
        [projectsApi.reducerPath]: projectsApi.reducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware().concat([

            authApi.middleware,
            userApi.middleware,
            projectsApi.middleware

        ]),
})
```

Here is my projectApi.js code , where i am calling my projectApi

```
    import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
    
    export const projectsApi = createApi({
        reducerPath: 'projectsApi',
        baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/api/v1' }),
    
        endpoints: (builder) => ({
            Project: builder.query({
                query(body) {
                    return {
                        url: '/projects',
                        method: 'POST',
                        body
                    }
                }
    
            }),
    
        })
    })
    export const { useAddProjectMutation } = projectsApi;
```

Now, let me provide a bit more context about the "Project" component. It seems to be the source of the error, and I'm struggling to identify the root cause. Here's a brief overview of the "Project" component:

```
const AddProject = () => {
    const [content, setContent] = useState({
        title: "",
        description: ""
    });
    const { title, description } = content;
    const { mutate: addProjectMutation, isLoading, error } = useAddProjectMutation();

    const submitHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const addProjectData = {
            title,
            description
        };

        try {
            await addProjectMutation(addProjectData);
            setContent({
                title: "",
                description: ""
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error adding project:", error);
        }
    };
    const onChange = (e) => {
        setContent({ ...content, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }
    return (
        <div className='row'>
            <div className='col-12'>
                <h2>Add Project</h2>
                <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                    <div className='form-group'>
                        <ReactQuill
                            theme='snow'
                            value={content.description} 
                            onChange={onChange}
                        />

                    </div>
                    <button id="add_button" type="submit" className="btn w-100 py-2" disabled={isLoading}>
                        {isLoading ? "Creating..." : "Add Project"}
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AddProject;
```

Here is the error
[image]